# Deactivate openbox desktop context menu on 2nd screen

Tags: debian, desktop, lxde, openbox, menu

I'm using Debian Stretch LXDE (OpenBox) in a dual monitor setup. I activated the openbox context menu of my second screen by setting

```
Desktop (right click) -> Desktop Preferences -> Advanced (Tab) -> Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked (Checkbox)
```

My 1st screen context menu appears as it defaults.

So how do I activate the OpenBox context menu on the 2nd screen?

I already tried to figure out some settings in `/etc/xdg/openbox/...` but with no clear results.

**Edit**

To clarify my problem: Every screen has its own settings, available by `Desktop (right click) -> Desktop Preferences` per default. As soon as I activated the window manager context menu the `Desktop Preferences` disappears and I can't undo my settings.

**Edit (2017-12-05)**

Left screen desktop context menu
[image: Left screen desktop context menu]

Right screen desktop context menu
[image: Right screen desktop context menu]

The setting caused the right screen desktop context menu, originally made on the right screen desktop
[image: The setting caused the right screen desktop context menu](![Left screen desktop context menu]

Comment: What do you mean with context menu? The root-menu of Openbox (`menu.xml`)? Or the window-list menu of Openbox? Also it might be helpful to see your `rc.xml`.

Comment: I added some screenshots. Every screen provides its own dekstop context menu. And I like to deactivate the openbox context menu on the right one, I activated by checking the option shown on the 3rd screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to re-enable the PCmanFM Desktop, this is the software which gives you the Windows like menu with create new, etc.

I haven't found the exact option which allows you to do this, but from the [PCmanFM wiki](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM), [the man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/pcmanfm#~/.config/pcmanfm/default/desktop-items-0.conf), and the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCManFM) I gathered, that there should be an option in the `~/.config/pcmanfm/default/desktop-items-$XYZ.conf` where $XYZ is a number for your screen starting from zero.

There you should find an option to switch the menu from PCmanFM back on.
But I don't know which the name of the option and the possible values. But by comparing the two files you will have you should see a relevant difference.

So running

```
diff ~/.config/pcmanfm/default/desktop-items-*.conf
```

Should give you a good clue.

In addition there is `~/.config/pcmanfm/default/pcmanfm.conf` for genereal options.

Comment: Feel yourself gifted with beer as much as you can drink! To be specific the solution is to set `show_wm_menu=0` in the `desktop-items-*.conf` file in question.